# What is a keyboard shortcut for the Multiple Element selection functionality in Selenium IDE?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, selenium-ide

How can I select multiple elements of application in Selenium IDE those are selected by user after pressing ctrl key ?

Which command is used for this feature?

Comment: it is not clear what you are asking for, try to describe more about it.

Comment: I assume the user is trying to do a multi select field? like the one herE: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT_MULTIPLE.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using addSelection (in combination with select command):

```
<tr>
    <td>select</td>
    <td>//select[@name='toppings']</td>
    <td>olives</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>addSelection</td>
    <td>//select[@name='toppings']</td>
    <td>mushrooms</td>
</tr>
```

This example will work with the html snippet on http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_SELECT_MULTIPLE.html :

```
<select name="toppings" multiple="multiple" size="5" id="dougtest" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><option value="mushrooms">mushrooms
</option><option value="greenpeppers">green peppers
</option><option value="onions">onions
</option><option value="tomatoes">tomatoes
</option><option value="olives">olives
</option></select>
```